# Error : Faileld to run "ant -version" in build cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I have a problem that when I write command "cordova build android" to build my project ,shown me above error, but I download and installed Apache Ant:

```
Error : Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant install to your path.
at  D:\hello\platforms\android\cordova\lib\chek_reqs.js:43:27
at Childprocess.exithandler <child_process.js:652:7>
at Childprocess.emit <events.js:756:16>
```

and

```
ERROR building one of the platforms : Error: D:\hello\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat : Command failed with exit code 8
you may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

what I did wrong?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you run `ant -version` in a console (Win+R > `cmd` on Windows) ? If you can't you have to add **ant** to  environment variables (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: More on Ant setup: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup

Comment: Although I added ant to environment variables ,shown me that !!

Comment: If `ant -version` gives you an error, you didn't put the environment variable correctly. Where is ant installed on your disk? You have to put `c:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin\` to PATH (you will need to close the console and reopen it)

Comment: It is correct, thank's a loooooot Gorcyn... .